# What is the difference between Zuul and Feign client?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have an EDG service which is a gateway in front of some services,
those services were reached by feign client so all requests come to edge and it's controllers will forward the request to back end service using fegin client.

I thought that's bad so I wanted to change this by fully using Zuul integration, that will automatically do the routing to the backend services , load balancing ...etc

The problem is: handing zuul filters to do centralized logging is not so cool vs fegin client which is just a call and I can make global Exception handler to handle exceptions ...etc

so what is the correct way of implementing the Edge layer?

Comment: Feign is an http client, zuul is an api gateway. They don't really compare

Comment: You can't compare this.zuul is an API gateway in spring cloud architecture. For example in microservice world all API Request call through API gateway. feign client is REST client for service communication. Earlier time REST template used for service inter communication. But now REST Template deprecated.

Comment: @dneranjan I know, but as I described you can make your gateway buy defining some controller mappings and use feign client to route to back-end services and it's already load balanced using Ribbon , so why not using it in this way as a gateway ?

Comment: @emadomara In microservice architecture , API gateway normally we use for as a single entry for all clients. And we can also use API gateway common implementation .such as Authentication &Authorization, log implementation ,rate limit , ... etc.

Comment: Yes, as @spencergibb indicates, they have very different purposes. You can make a call with feign client from a service to another service via the gateway; so you actually direct the calls to the gateway and they get rerouted there. One more thing to consider while using the Spring Cloud stack is that if you are going to use a gateway, you should go rather for Spring Cloud Gateway and not SC Netflix Zuul, as the latter is now in maintenance mode and will not be available in 2020.0.0 release train.